# Python: check every word in each line of a list, and check that word is the same as a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

this is my basic code.

```
for key in dictionary: #Here key is the actually variable defined in key:value pair
  for line in list:
    if key in line: 
        print key
```

error value I get in return is

if key in line:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

I used this to encode Non-ascii values

```
unicode = u"\xc3\x81"
encoded= unicode.encode('utf-8')
```

I noticed that some of the type(key) were int so I hope to above code fixed that.

I have look through many resources and haven't been convinced of a way to check each word in a list for the keyword string in a dictionary.

Also I have been told not to make the dictionary a list via dictionary.keys()
or vice versa with the list.

Comment: yes,  I got confused with the pusedo code.

Comment: just checked its same error message

Comment: May not be related to your issue, but you should try to avoid naming your variables with names for built in classes. list is a class for building or converting to python lists.

Comment: I think @kojiro may have been asking to see the traceback

Comment: @bsoist that wasn't what I was asking for – earlier edits had `if key in list:` and the error message displayed the same text: `if key in list…`. OP updated the code sample, but had forgotten to update the error message at first.

Comment: @kojiro, sorry for not informing you right away.  I'm not updated with comment etiquette.

Comment: You don't have to inform me of anything – I was just responding to @bsoist

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is some code missing. Most likely what is happening is that somewhere in your code you are concatenating a unicode string and an int:

```
a = u"unicode str"
b = 5

print(a + b)
```

**On a side note** - regarding the code:

```
unicode = u"\xc3\x81"
encoded= unicode.encode('utf-8')
```

This doesn't look right. Your first line is definitely not unicode - it's probably UTF-8, and you want to `decode` instead.

```
unicode = "\xc3\x81"
encoded = unicode.decode('utf-8')
print encoded  # prints Á
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like:

```
mydict = {"is": 1, "the": 2}
```

and

```
list = ["Line is the first", "Line is the second",]
```

You should try:

```
>>> for line in list:
    for w in line.split(" "):
       print("Word", w, " in key list:", w in mydict.keys())

('Word', 'Line', ' in key list:', False)
('Word', 'is', ' in key list:', True)
('Word', 'the', ' in key list:', True)
('Word', 'first', ' in key list:', False)
('Word', 'Line', ' in key list:', False)
('Word', 'is', ' in key list:', True)
('Word', 'the', ' in key list:', True)
('Word', 'second', ' in key list:', False)
>>>
```

Usually Python will handle the unicode for you so that you should be able to compare the strings without you having to worry.

Comment: thanks you are awesome!  It makes sense that I would have to split the line into words.